# Using one list to find mean of three variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In the following code, I declare three list just to find the mean of three variable. Could the code be more concise? e.g., using one list.

```
import numpy as np
rmse_train_arr=[]
wt_error_train_arr=[]
rmse_test_arr=[]
for i in range(5):
    rmse_train = i
    wt_error_train=i+5
    rmse_test=i+6

    rmse_train_arr.append(rmse_train)
    wt_error_train_arr.append(wt_error_train)
    rmse_test_arr.append(rmse_test)

print(np.array(rmse_train_arr).mean(),np.array(wt_error_train_arr).mean(),np.array(rmse_test_arr).mean())
```

`for i in range(5)` is just simplification for the purpose of asking here, in reality, you can assume you can't know the exact value of `rmse_train`, `wt_error_train`, etc during the for loop. The purpose simply to find their mean at the end.

Comment: `rmse_train_arr = np.arange(5); wt_error_train_arr = rmse_train_arr + 5; rmse_test_arr = rmse_train_arr + 6`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq thanks, but the number `for i in range(5)` is just simplification for the purpose of asking here, in reality, you can assume you can't know the exact value of `rmse_train`, `wt_error_train`,etc during the for loop. The purpose simply to find their mean at the end.

Comment: If they're not vectorizable like this, then what you've got is probably the best that can be done.

Comment: Do you know the length? I mean how many times the loop iterates, if you know that you don't need the lists, just keep a running sum for each of the variables an divide by the length.

Comment: You can also simplify your last expression `np.array([rmse_test_arr, wt_error_train_arr, rmse_test_arr]).mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @DanielMesejo We don't know for the length

Comment: You can do it with a single list, or at least I can think of a solution, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: @DanielMesejo I am thinking of a list of tuples, but tuples won't get the mean for each position if we do the mean for the list

Comment: @DanielMesejo Something like `print(np.array([(1,2),(3,4)]).mean())`, but it does not work, as it will result in single number, rather than a tuple

Comment: Also even if you dont know the length you can keep the count as an aditional variable.

Answer (score 0):

In think this is a better approach to keeping lists:

```
rmse_train_mean = 0
wt_error_train_mean = 0
rmse_test_mean = 0
counter = 0  # if you don't know how many elements there are

for i in range(5):
    rmse_train = i
    wt_error_train = i + 5
    rmse_test = i + 6

    rmse_train_mean += rmse_train
    wt_error_train_mean += wt_error_train
    rmse_test_mean += rmse_test

    counter += 1

print(rmse_train_mean / counter, wt_error_train_mean / counter, rmse_test_mean / counter)
```

**Output**

```
2.0 7.0 8.0
```

There is at least one way of keeping a single  list, if you must, but only if you must:

```
import numpy as np

one = []

for i in range(5):
    rmse_train = i
    wt_error_train = i + 5
    rmse_test = i + 6

    one.extend([rmse_train, wt_error_train, rmse_test])

result = np.mean([one[::3], one[1::3], one[2::3]], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
[2. 7. 8.]
```

The first approach does it all in one pass and does not keep several (or one) list in memory.

Comment: Thanks, the list approach intuitive enough but ugly.